# Reactive Webflux for toggle server - is it beneficial?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

We have a need to implement a simple toggle server (rest application) that would take the toggle name and return if it is enabled or disabled. We are expecting a load of 10s of thousands of requests per day.

Does Spring (reactive) webflux makes sense here?

My understanding is reactive rest apis will be useful if there is any possibility of idle time of the http thread - meaning thread waiting for some job to be done and it can't proceed until it receives the response like from db reads or rest calls to other services.

Our use case is just to return the toggle value (probably from some cache) that is being queried. Will the reactive rest service be useful in our case? Does it provide any advantages over simple spring boot application?

Comment: WebFlux is good for IO intensive applications. `10s of thousands requests per day` does NOT sound a lot to me assuming they are all equally distributed. You would not notice any performance gain until you see many concurrent IO requests. So you can go with whatever you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm coming from a background of "traditional" spring/spring-mvc apps development experience, and these days I'm also starting to learn spring webflux and based on the data provided in the question here are my observations (disclaimer: since I'm a beginner in this area as I said, take this answer with a grain of salt):

1. WebFlux is less "straight forward" to implement compared to the traditional application: the maintenance cost is higher, the debugging is harder, etc.
2. WebFlux will shine if your operations are I/O bound. If you're going to read the data from in-memory cache - this is not an I/O bound operation. I also understand that the nature of "toggle" data is that it doesn't change that much, but gets accessed (read) frequently, hence keeping it in some memory cache indeed makes sense here, unless you build something huge that won't fit in memory at all, but this is a different story.
3. WebFlux + netty will let you to serve **simultaneously** thousands of requests, tomcat, having a traditional "thread per request" model, still allows 200 threads + 100 in the queue by default, if you exceed these values it will fail, but netty will "survive". Based on the data presented in the question, I don't see you'll benefit from netty here.
   10s of thousands requests per day seems like something that any kind of server can handle easily, tomcat, jetty, whatever - you don't need that "high-load" here.
4. As I've mentioned in item "3" WebFlux is good in **simultaneous** request handling, but you probably won't gain any **performance improvement** over the traditional approach, its not about the speed, its about the better resource utilization.
5. If you're going to read the data from the database and you do want to go with webflux, make sure you do have reactive drivers for your database - when you run the flow, you should be "reactive" all the way, blocking on db access doesn't make sence.

So, bottom line, If I were you, I would have started with a regular server and consider moving to reactive stack later (probably this "later" will never come as long the expectations specified in the questions don't change).

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it aims to minimize thread idling and getting more performance by using *fewer* threads than in a traditional multithreading approach where a thread per request is used, or in reality a pool of worker threads to prevent too many threads being created.

If you're only getting tens of thousands of requests per day, and your use case is as simple as that, it doesn't sound like you need to plan anything special for it. A regular webapp will perform just fine.